# filter an array of object from another array's value JS

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of objects like this:
If content tags have a value, it should be filter from another array.

```
let mainArray = [
{
    "contentTitle": "Article 2 Test",
    "contentTags": [
        "Movies",
        "Stories"
    ],
    "contentPagePath": "global/en/top-page/listing-page/article2.html"
},
{

    "contentTitle": "Sub Article page",
    "contentTags": [
        "test",
        "Podcasts"
    ],
    "contentPagePath": "global/en/top-page/listing-page/article1/sub-article-page.html"
},
{
    "contentTitle": "Page title article",
    "contentTags": [
        "books",
        "hotels"
    ],
    "contentPagePath": "global/en/top-page/listing-page/article1.html"
    
},
{
    "contentTitle": "Article 5",
    "contentTags": [
        "random",
        "random2"
    ],
    "contentPagePath": "global/en/top-page/listing-page/article-new5.html"
}];
```

Now I have another array from which I want to filter the above array.

```
let filterArray = ["Movies", "Podcasts"];
```

Now I want the result from the above array's keys **contentTags** have any of the value from 2nd array.

so After filter Result should be.

```
[
{
    "contentTitle": "Article 2 Test",
    "contentTags": [
        "Movies",
        "Stories"
    ],
    "contentPagePath": "global/en/top-page/listing-page/article2.html"
},
{

    "contentTitle": "Sub Article page",
    "contentTags": [
        "test",
        "Podcasts"
    ],
    "contentPagePath": "global/en/top-page/listing-page/article1/sub-article-page.html"
}
]
```

Result is like this because the mainArray have 2 objects, one have Movies from filter object and 2nd have Podcasts from filteredobject In it.

Comment: _"Now I want the result"_ - please share a [mcve] of your effort so far

Comment: the naive approach is `items.filter(item => item.contentTags.some(tag => query.includes(tag)))` where `query` is your array of tags to filter.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) with [`some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) to achieve that goal

```js
const mainArray=[{contentTitle:"Article 2 Test",contentTags:["Movies","Stories"],contentPagePath:"global/en/top-page/listing-page/article2.html"},{contentTitle:"Sub Article page",contentTags:["test","Podcasts"],contentPagePath:"global/en/top-page/listing-page/article1/sub-article-page.html"},{contentTitle:"Page title article",contentTags:["books","hotels"],contentPagePath:"global/en/top-page/listing-page/article1.html"},{contentTitle:"Article 5",contentTags:["random","random2"],contentPagePath:"global/en/top-page/listing-page/article-new5.html"}];

const filterArray = ["Movies", "Podcasts"];

const result = mainArray.filter(item => item.contentTags.some(contentTag => filterArray.includes(contentTag)))

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a combination of filter and find to achieve the above scenario:

```
contents.filter((d) => d.contentTags.find(e => targetTags.indexOf(e) > -1))
```

Here I am applying `filter` on the *contents* array which is your source array and it will return the objects which only passes the find logic which I have return. Inner `find` will loop the *contentTags* and check if it exists in your comparison tags array.